# Filled.contour does not plot all my matrix (y axis cropped)

Tags: r, r-raster

After preparing my irregular dataset into a regular grid (using `interp`), I want to plot the data using `filled.contour`. I did it a few times already and it worked well so far. Somehow this time, it seems that filled.contour is cropping my dataset at a certain y value. I have checked the matrix produced by `interp` and it looks good so I have no idea why it does that.

Here are clickable links to my data, the produced raster and a plot:

[original dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fayzldzxlihxalv/Sr_All_noES.txt?dl=0)

```
Sr.All_ln<-interp(Sr.All$Lon, y = Sr.All$Lat, z = Sr.All$`Sr isot`, duplicate = "mean")
```

[here is the matrix done with interp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/97mmdi22k8mneaa/Sr_All_ln_noES.txt?dl=0)

```
filled.contour(Sr.All_ln, plot.axes = {axis(1);axis(2);points(Sr.All$Lon,Sr.All$Lat, pch=16)})
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXGFO.png)

I would be very grateful if someone has a fix! Thanks in advance and have a great day!

Comment: How are we supposed to help if you do not provide example data?

Comment: Well, I thought I did in the clickable links ("original dataset", "matrix done with interp" and "result")? Or is it not what you mean? I can re-edit the post if it is too confusing.

Comment: For ease here are the RData of my original dataset: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3fzz7s6sapae7w/Sr_all.RData?dl=0) and of the raster produced with interp: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ajo4a897gt5j6yk/Sr_all_ln.RData?dl=0) - I must add that running interp on that dataset makes Rstudio crash, so I am wondering if it is not too big? Thanks for your help!